# Bundle in Karaf using wrong pax-jdbc DataSource

Tags: java, jdbc, datasource, apache-karaf, pax

We have different OSGi bundles loaded in Karaf 4.0.3 and multiple `javax.sql.DataSource` loaded by `pax-jdbc-config`. For example, there are configured two datasources to different databases:

```
karaf@root()> service:list DataSource
[javax.sql.DataSource]
----------------------
 dataSourceName = datasourceA
 felix.fileinstall.filename = file:/opt/karaf/etc/org.ops4j.datasource-dba.cfg
 osgi.jdbc.driver.name = mysql-pool
 osgi.jndi.service.name = datasourceA
 password = secretpassword
 service.bundleid = 207
 service.factoryPid = org.ops4j.datasource
 service.id = 276
 service.pid = org.ops4j.datasource.2ab06071-d3fa-4d7e-b508-19f36892cb7e
 service.scope = singleton
 url = jdbc:mysql://mysql.example.com/dba
 user = dbuser
Provided by : 
 OPS4J Pax JDBC Config (207)
Used by: 
 MODULE B (29)

[javax.sql.DataSource]
----------------------
 dataSourceName = datasourceB
 felix.fileinstall.filename = file:/opt/karaf/etc/org.ops4j.datasource-dbb.cfg
 osgi.jdbc.driver.name = PostgreSQL JDBC Driver-pool
 osgi.jndi.service.name = datasourceB
 password = secretpassword
 service.bundleid = 207
 service.factoryPid = org.ops4j.datasource
 service.id = 278
 service.pid = org.ops4j.datasource.a7b84423-a605-4010-9806-db7bcc0bccd4
 service.scope = singleton
 url = jdbc:postgresql://postgresql.example.com/dbb
 user = dbuser
Provided by : 
 OPS4J Pax JDBC Config (207)
```

My problem is that bundle **MODULE B** should use **datasourceB**. It is configured to use **datasourceB** in all source files and in *blueprint.xml*

```
...
<reference id="datasourceB" interface="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
...
```

I really don't understand, how easily can karaf bundles use different DataSource.

And when **datasourceA** config file is removed, then **MODULE B** correctly use **datasourceB**.

Is this issue about wrong *order* of config files or something?

**EDIT :**
I have found out that when I remove **datasourceA** config file and therefore Karaf removes that DataSource (not present in `service:list DataSource`), **MODULE B** correctly uses **datasourceB**.

But I still don't know why is this happening. Did I missed read some documentation about this? Is it `pax-jdbc-config` issue or Karaf issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you reference the datasource, you can use a filter to indicate wich one you want :

```
<reference id="datasourceB" interface="javax.sql.DataSource" filter="(dataSourceName=datasourceB)" />
```

Comment: Oh my god, you are probably right! I didn't realise modules can't know which datasource I mean, because I just set the ID of reference, but no actual reference.. Thank you!